# Alamofire data send with HTTPBody issue

Tags: ios, iphone, httprequest, alamofire

I'm trying to make api request with Alamofire. Data want to send with body. heare is what im doing.

```
let URL : String = "\(BaseUrl.sharedInstance.URL)\(EndPoint)"

do {
       let options = NSJSONWritingOptions()
       let data = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(RequestData, options: options)
       let jsons = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)


       let mutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: URL)!)
       mutableURLRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"
       mutableURLRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
       mutableURLRequest.HTTPBody = data


       Alamofire.request(mutableURLRequest)
                .response { request, response, data, error in
                    print(request)
                    let dataString = NSString(data: data!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                    print(dataString)
                    print(response)
                    print(error)
    }

    } catch {
            print("JSON serialization failed:  \(error)")
    }
```

anyone have idea about it.

Comment: whats the problem here ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, URLString, parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON, headers: headerss).responseJSON
        {
            response in switch response.result
            {
            case .Success(let JSON):

                let response = JSON as! NSDictionary
                print (response);

                onSuccess (response)

                //example if there is an id

            case .Failure(let error):

                onFailure (error);
                print("Request failed with error: \(error)")

            }
    }
```